# 3' terminal phosphate (p at the end of RNA sequence)

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-biology, dna-rna

I am reading the paper:

**Petersheim, M. and Turner, D.H. (1983) Base-stacking and base-pairing contributions to helix stability: thermodynamics of double-helix formation with CCGG, CCGGp, CCGGAp, ACCGGp, CCGGUp, and ACCGGUp. Biochemistry, 22, 256-263.**

The **p** at the end of the sequence apparently stands for **3'-terminal phosphate**.

What is the difference between RNA sequences with a 3' terminal phosphate and a "normal" RNA sequence? Why would they consider RNA with a 3' terminal phosphate?

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe it's related to [how oligonucleotides are made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligonucleotide_synthesis#Synthesis_by_the_phosphoramidite_method)? That first phosphoramidite would have a 3' phosphorous attached, which would become a 3' phosphate upon cleavage from the support. This could be removed after synthesis, or it could be left attached.